# pass two models to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I am new to mvc and try to learn it by doing a small project with it. I have a page which is supposed to display that specific date's currencies and weather. so I should pass currencies model and weather model. I have done to pass currencies model and works fine but I dont know how to pass the second model. And most of the tutorials on the shows how to pass only one model.

can you guys give an idea how to do it.

this is my current controller action which sends currency model

```
public ActionResult Index(int year,int month,int day)
    {
        var model = from r in _db.Currencies
                    where r.date == new DateTime(year,month,day)
                    select r;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Simply create an aggregate model class with 2 models you need to pass as properties.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can create special viewmodel that contains both models:

```
public class CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies{get;set;}
   public Weather CurrentWeather {get;set;}
}
```

and pass it to view.

```
public ActionResult Index(int year,int month,int day)
{
    var currencies = from r in _db.Currencies
                where r.date == new DateTime(year,month,day)
                select r;
    var weather = ...

    var model = new CurrencyAndWeatherViewModel {Currencies = currencies.ToArray(), CurrentWeather = weather};

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: How do I access the different models from the view after passing them successfully?

Comment: model.Currencies to get properties from Currencies and model.CurrentWeather  go get properties from CurrentWeather

Comment: @model does not exist in current context inside html

Answer (score 6):

You have to create a new model which has to contain the whole objects that you want to pass it to view. You should create a model (class, object) which inherits the base model (class, object).

And other suggestion you may send objects (models) via View["model1"] and View["model2"] or just an array that contains objects to pass it and cast them inside the view which I don't advise .

Comment: how do u send them with View ? how do you pass it from controller to view

Comment: In Controller class `ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();` and in view page `<div>
<%: ViewData["CurrentTime"] %>
</div>` for more details this link may help [link](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1310-how-to-pass-data-from-controllers-to-views-in-aspnet-mvc-tutorial-no-2.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could use a model that is specific to this view.

```
public class MyViewModel{

  public List<Currencies> CurrencyList {get;set;}

}
```

and then from your controller you could pass this new View Model into the view instead:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int year,int month,int day)
    {
        var model = from r in _db.Currencies
                    where r.date == new DateTime(year,month,day)
                    select r;

        return View(new MyViewModel { CurrencyList = model.ToList() });
    }
```

You can than just add more properties to your view model which contain any other models (Weather model) and set them appropriately.