# Pass two models to view without using ViewModel approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to know that is it possible to pass two Models simultaneously in a view without using ViewModel approach ?

Comment: possible answer is here

[Pass two models to a view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030399/pass-two-models-to-view

Comment: @ZohaibAslam I know very well that I can do that with ViewModel approach.But I don't want to use the ViewModel.

Comment: I think viewmodel is the best approach but i have used a class once you can check it out "Tuple". This class can contain different types.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can use a `Tuple<T1, T2>`...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new Tuple<Foo, Bar>(new Foo(), new Bar()));
}
```

View:

```
@model Tuple<Foo, Bar>

...

<div class="container">
    Foo value = @Model.Item1.Value
    <hr />
    Bar value = @Model.Item2.Value
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eDOSZU)

Comment: I thought he does not want to use the ViewModel?

Comment: I took that to mean he/she doesn't want to create a view model class (which I think is a better practice), but still wants to pass the two models to the view without using dynamics (e.g., ViewBag).

Comment: @derape Actually Someone asked about this..so i am curious to know Is it only this way or there is another way..:)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to worry about binding then you can just use the ViewBag, e.g.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.FirstModel = new FirstModel();
    ViewBag.SecondModel = new SecondModel();

    return View();
}
```

The models are then available in the view via the ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TempData` or `ViewData`. You can even use Session or Cache. I prefer the ViewModel approach though as it is what it's intended for. I tend to only use TempData or ViewData to fill in select lists.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible ways are by using the following

ViewData
ViewBag
TempData

Here is the whole code sample for each, take a look. hope it helps

[Passing multiple models to view using ViewData, ViewBag, TempData](http://codeanalyze.com/Articles/Details/21/MVC-5-Passing-multiple-models-to-view-MVC-ASPNET-ViewModel-ViewData-ViewBag-TempData)