# MVC Display 2 models in 1 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable

**Controller**

```
public class CurrentAndHist
{
    public IEnumerable<CurrentApplication> CurrentApplications { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<History> Histories { get; set; }
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //var ca = db.CurrentApplications.ToList();
    //var hist = db.Histories.ToList();
    //return View(staffs.Where(IsDeleted = false));

    var ca = db.CurrentApplications.ToList();
    var hist = db.Histories.ToList();

    var model = new CurrentAndHist { CurrentApplications = ca, Histories = hist };

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<LeaveApplication.Models.CurrentApplication>

<body>
    <h3 class="text-custom animated bounceInDown">Current Applications</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table animated bounceInDown">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Start Date", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("End Date", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Type", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Application Date", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Period", "Index")
                </th>
            </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LeaveType)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppStatus)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoOfDays)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", new {  })';return false;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", new { })';return false;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", new {  })' ;return false;">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </table>
    </div>

    <br /><br />
    <h3 class="text-custom animated bounceInDown">Application History</h3>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table animated bounceInDown">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Start Date", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("End Date", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Type", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Status", "Index")
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Period", "Index")

                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LeaveType)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppStatus)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="table-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoOfDays)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", new { })';return false;">
                        <span style="margin-right: 5px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>Details
                    </button>
                </td>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have 2 tables in a page and both tables display data from different models. Current Applications table holds data from the CurrentApplications model while History table holds data from the Histories model. I tried solutions from other users - [pass two models to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030399/pass-two-models-to-view) but it didn't work for me and I got the error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'LeaveApplication.Controllers.LeaveController+CurrentAndHist', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LeaveApplication.Models.CurrentApplication]'.

I tried changing to `@model IEnumerable<LeaveApplication.Models.CurrentAndHist>` but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the model in your view to

```
@model yourAssembly.CurrentAndHist
```

and use 2 loops to generate the items

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CurrentApplications )
{
  @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.StartDate)
  ....
}
@foreach (var item in Model.Histories)
{
  ....
}
```