# Trying to create view with 2 models gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

So what im trying to do is make a view with 2 of my models. For that i made this **viewmodel**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TimeTrackerProjectV2.Models
{
    public class TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<TimeSheet_Details> Details { get; set; }
        public TimeSheetInfo Info { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a **controller** method that returns my viewmodel to my view like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var inf = Repositories.TimeSheetRepository.GetTimesheetInfo(id);
            var time = Repositories.Timesheet_DetailsRepo.GetTimeSheetThroughId(id);
            var model = new TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel { Details = time.ToList(), Info = inf };

            return View(model);
        }
```

My **view** currently looks like this:

```
  @model IEnumerable<TimeTrackerProjectV2.Models.TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <dt>
        Month
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model =>)
    </dd>

    <dt>
      Year
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Year)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Year
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Year)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        Status
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.StatusUnparsed)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        User
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.EmailUser)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Explanation
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Explanation)
    </dd>
}
}
</dl>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Project
        </th>
        <th>
             Task  
        </th>
        <th>
             Time Spent
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        foreach( var i in item.Details)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.DayOfMonth )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Project)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Task)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.TimeSpent)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }

</table>
```

I get an error because im passing a single ModelView object while my view is expecting a ennumeration. But when i change so that my view expects a single object i cant call the value of my Object Entities inside my ViewModel because i cant do a foreach with my viewmodel anymore. Hope it makes sence what im trying to say. What is the best way to accomplish this?

[Where i got my controller code example from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030399/pass-two-models-to-view)

Comment: first, what's that? `@Html.DisplayFor(model =>)`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You need to change the declaration to `@model TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel` and use just `@foreach (var item in Model.Details)` (not a `foreach(var item in Model)`)

Comment: You're using `IEnumerable` collection instead of a single `TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel` model. Putting `foreach` loop after passing to view page is more appropriate.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ty worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use a declaration of IEnumerable in your view.
Just put those lines in your view page:

```
   @model TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
    {
        <dt>
            Month
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Month)
        </dd>

        <dt>
          Year
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Year)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            Year
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Year)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            Status
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.StatusUnparsed)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            User
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.EmailUser)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Explanation
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Explanation)
        </dd>
    }
    </dl>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Project
            </th>
            <th>
                 Task  
            </th>
            <th>
                 Time Spent
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.DayOfMonth )
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Project)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.Task)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.TimeSpent)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are trying to iterate through your Model which isn't iterable. Second thing that bothers me is that you have `DisplayFor` referencing to nothing (next to the month label).

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but your code has couple of errors, but try changing the following (I omitted some code for the brevity):

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">  
    <dt>
      Year
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Info.Year)
    </dd>   
</dl>


 foreach(var detail in model.Details)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x=> detail.DayOfMonth)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x=> detail.Project)
            </td>
        </tr>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is a single object that has within it an enumeration, so this needs to change:

```
@model IEnumerable<TimeTrackerProjectV2.Models.TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel>
```

to

```
@model TimeTrackerProjectV2.Models.TimesheetInfoAndTimeSheet_DetailsViewModel
```

You don't need a foreach loop to reference you model.Info as there is only one so the first foreach loop can go and you can simply change references from

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Info.Year)
```

to

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Info.Year)
```

Your final foreach loop will change from

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

to

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Details)
```